# How to scrape a popup window using casperjs

Tags: php, casperjs

when im trying to scrape a webpage using casperjs,there is a new window(popup window) opened. i can`t enter into popup window from parent window. Is this possible with casperjs? if not possible suggest another way.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: No. Now i just getting the url, bt i want to enter into popup window and scrap the content of popup. Also i need mouse action events in casperjs on popup

Comment: You need to add your code into this question.

Comment: https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/internet:982 in displayPolicy
https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/internet:1204 in onload
url popup loaded : https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/ENULogin.jsp
completed:https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/ENULogin.jsp
url popup loaded : https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/ENULogin.jsp
completed:https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/ENULogin.jsp
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 8000ms.

Comment: `https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/internet:982 in displayPolicy'
'https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/internet:1204 in onload'
'url popup loaded : https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/ENULogin.jsp
url popup loaded : https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/ENULogin.jsp
but i want to enter into that perticular page (popup page, https://www.irinstechnologies.com/B001/internet/id=?). IT just shows this link into the server,bt i dont get to redirect it. Popup window is generated automatically with different id's.

Comment: i mean, the code of the CasperJS script.

Comment: $casper->wait(mt_rand(300, 450));
$fragment = <<<FRAGMENT
casper.thenClick('.btnsignin', function() {
 casper
.on('popup.created', function() {
    this.echo("url popup created : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
 
})
.on('popup.loaded', function() {
   this.echo("url popup loaded : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
    var va=this.getCurrentUrl();
 this.echo('completed:' + va); 
});
 
});
FRAGMENT;
$casper->extraFunction($fragment);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [withPopup()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#withpopup) `and/or` [waitForPopup()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforpopup)

And also these callbacks:

```
casper
.on('popup.created', function() {
    this.echo("url popup created : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
})
.on('popup.loaded', function() {
    this.echo("url popup loaded : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
});
```